# searching a multi-dimensional array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

Follow up question regarding searching a multi-dimensional array.
Suppose you have a Contacts array: FirstName, LastName, Email(), Mobile#, Work#, etc. where each Contact object can have multiple emails.

Objective: Find a Contact object by searching the email(s) field.  i.e. use email address to find & return the full Contact object so I can subsequently display info from the Contact object to the user for view, edit, etc.

I have been investigating find, filter, map... all good, but stuck on best approach and syntax using any of the Array iteration techniques to apply to a more complex, multi-dimensional array field (search the email field).

BTW, I just taught myself Javascript (well,actually web resources taught me) and apologize in advance if this is a remedial, rookie question...

Comment: Are you able to share an example of the data structure you're trying to search? It's a bit difficult to understand the problem without seeing how the data is structured.

Comment: I am coding in Google Appscript, 
// The code below will retrieve all the user's contacts
    var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
Returns: Contact []     an array of all the user's contacts.
Array structure is: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact
As you can imagine, a Contact has several 1:n relationships such as email, phone, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### Update for GAPI

So using the GAPI docs, you'll want something like:

```
function findContactByEmail(contacts, email) {
  return contacts.find(contact => {
    return contact.getEmails().some(contactEmail => {
      return contactEmail.getAddress() === email
    })
  )
}
```

This function will return the first contact found that contains the search email in its list of email addresses.

---

### Original answer

I'm assuming your data looks something like:

```
[
  {
    firstName: "...",
    emails: [ "email1@domain.com", "email2@domain.com", ... ],
    ...
  }, ...
]
```

And you want a function that takes a list of Contacts and an email as input and returns the first Contact object that contains that email:

```
function findContactByEmail(contacts, email) {
  return contacts.find(contact => {
    return contact.emails.some(contactEmail => contactEmail === email)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) inside the callback of [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to identify a contact with a given email in their respective email array:

```js
var contacts = [
  {
    firstName: "Bob",
    emails: [ "bob@domain.com", "bobParr@domain2.com"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Sally",
    emails: [ "sally@domain.com", "sillySal@domain.com"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Joe",
    emails: [ "joe@domain.com", "mrJoe777@domain.com"],
  },
];

function findContactWithEmail(email) {
  return contacts.find(contact => contact.emails.includes(email));
}

console.log(findContactWithEmail('sillySal@domain.com'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for the help, it was enlightening and got me down the right path. To recap:

(1) The objective was to improve performance because the AppsScript Contacts Service was averaging about 2 seconds per request. My app can make 1-to-n requests based on user choice... and response time became an unacceptable 15, 20, 30 seconds between  and UI presentation.

(2) Testing found it takes on average 2 seconds to build a Contacts array containing 1500  gContact objects. And because the Contacts array is in memory, find requests are averaging below .5 seconds per find request.

Below is the conde that worked. Again, many thanks for helping this programming newbie!

```
/* Find gContacts that match emails extracted (xEmails) from Gmail messages, Calendar events, shared Drive documents. xEmails is an array of emails addresses name@domain.com.
   @param {string[]} emails | @return {Object[]} contact */

function findContacts(xEmails) { Logger.log('findContacts BEGIN');
  return xEmails.map(findContactByEmail).filter(function(gContact) {
    return gContact != null
  });
}
function findContactByEmail(xEmail) { Logger.log('findContactByEmail BEGIN', xEmail);
  return gContacts.find(contact => {
    return contact.getEmails().some(contactEmail => {
      return contactEmail.getAddress() === xEmail
    })
  })
}
```